# Unable to select any location in Azure SQL .I have Azure Visual Studio Professional Subscription

Tags: azure

I was trying to create Azure SQL resource but I am unable to select any location.I have Azure Visual Studio Professional Subscription.Can you please help?

[Azure error - unable to select location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPG4f.png)

Answer (score 0):

As replied here :
[Create SQL Database Server, Location (Africa) South Africa North](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/461b4364-1d76-4537-9f8e-3eb60d2ca137/create-sql-database-server-location-africa-south-africa-north?forum=ssdsgetstarted)

> This is probably because a
>   particular region is not activated for your subscription. Please
>   contact the Azure billing support to have this enabled for you. You
>   can contact then by going to out support page here on Azure Support